# Setting language as Turkish in nltk - part of speech tagging

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, pos-tagger

Is it possible to set language as Turkish in nltk - part of speech tagging?
If the answer is yes, how can I do it?

Comment: There's no turkish model in NLTK. But you can train one if you have annotated training data with NgramTagger or PerceptronTagger object.

Comment: @alvas I can start with collecting  verbs. They appear at the end of a regular sentence. How can I train this data ? Can you recommend me an easy-to-understand source?

Comment: @alvas can I go with naive-bayes classifier to train data?